# Where I can find a guide to aXe with java?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber, accessibility

I want to automate my accessibility test with selenium/java (and maybe with cucumber). Where can I find a guide or tutorial?
I know there is

> https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-selenium-java

But I don't understand this passage: `The simplest way to do this is to include it in your own src.test.resources and pass MyTest.class.getResource("/axe.min.js") to the Builder constructor as demonstrated in the ExampleTest.` Because I do not find the `ExampleTest`.
Could someone help me with this, please? :)

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ExampleTest`](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-selenium-java/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/deque/axe/ExampleTest.java) you're looking for lives under `src/test/java/com/deque/axe` folder of the repository you're referenced. Just in case you fail to find it one more time:

```
private static final URL scriptUrl = ExampleTest.class.getResource("/axe.min.js");

JSONObject responseJSON = new AXE.Builder(driver, scriptUrl).analyze();
```

There is a couple of alternative approaches you might find useful / easier to use:

- [Google Accessibility Developer Tools](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/accessibility-developer-tools) -> [Run audit from Selenium WebDriver](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/accessibility-developer-tools#run-audit-from-selenium-webdriver-scala)
- [Advanced Device Operations -> Web Content Accessibility](https://docs.experitest.com/display/LT/Accessibility)

Comment: how can I set the tags (for example 'wcag2a') ?

Comment: Check my article: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/integrate-axe-4-selenium-java-s-chathuranga-jayasinghe